# binding an array of collection's  to multiple itemscontrols respectively  

Tags: wpf, data-binding

iv'e got an array of collections ,  each is bounded to an itemscontrol 
in the following manner :

```
     ItemsContropl_n.ItemsSource= Collection[n-1] ;   
    .
    ItemsControl_15.ItemsSource= Collection[14] ;
    ItemsControl_14.ItemsSource= Collection[13] ; 
    .
    .
```

is there a way i could define the items source for each control relative to it collection counterpart
**something along the line of :**

the itemscontrols ancestor's DataContext  has a property which exposes the array of collections

```
  public Class Board 
  {
      public Coll [] Collections 
      {
         get { return collections;}
      }
  }


  CollectionPanel.DataContext = Board ;

  <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl_i" itemsSource="{Binding Path=Coll[i-1]" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes but you will hve to use another parent `ItemsControl`...

```
   <ItemsControl DataContext={Binding MyBoardInstance}
                 ItemsSource={Binding Collections}>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>   
             <ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding}>
                 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <!-- Your Template goes here -->
                       </DataTemplate>
                 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
             </ItemsControl>
           </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

No.  Would it simplify things to contruct a List of your ItemsControls and then just do your binding in code by iterating through your ItemsControls and your Collections?  It may help else where to have your controls in a collection if its a grid style board.

```
for (int i=0; i<my_controls; i++)
    my_controls[i].ItemsSource = Collection[i];
```

Comment: but then i would need to add some real ugly code in order to place them in a list ...(the thing i'm trying to avoid.